# SPServices - Problems reading from a list on a public site with anonymous access

Tags: 2007, web-services, spservices, anonymous-authentication

I'm trying to use SPServices to read from a list, store the data in some arrays and call the data back onto a page when it's needed. This works in the back-end version of our site (where our authors edit their pages and then they must be approved by admins before they're published and made live), but when published out this error shows on the page:

> Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

I'm calling the script through a Content Editor Web Part via a text file. Anonymous access is enabled on the text file as well as the lists that the script is referencing. Does anyone have any idea as to what might be causing this and how to get around it?

Thanks in advance,

Ash

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read from lists where the permissions are set to allow anonymous access.

Since you haven't posted you code, I can't tell you if anything is wrong with it, but it sounds like it's entirely a permissions error. Make sure that the script is loaded in the page on the browser end and that the script file is set for all to read.

If none of that works, look at the Net traffic with Firebug or Fiddler to see what the specific error is (if any).